# Should my projects folder and Github folder be the same?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Github and wanted to find out if it's bad practise to use the Projects folder (from which i'm working in) as the same folder which Github scans for changes?

Right now I work in my projects folder, make changes as needed. When I want to commit I then copy the contents of that folder into the Github folder which contains the branch. I then commit these changes.
What i'm asking is, is it OK to point Github to my projects folder instead of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is OK but you're completely missing the point (elegance) of git with regards to working in a separate folder then copying back into the original.  Take a look at branching, they're a free and easy first class citizen in Git and one of the real strengths of the product.

GitHub has no notion of scanning for changes.  Git is a Distributed Version Control System (DVCS).  There is no connection to the remote repository from your machine until you explicitly execute a command such as push, pull, clone etc.  The GitHub repository is just one of potentially many that your local repository can be connected to.

There are a huge number of resources out there regarding git but try [Think Like a Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) as it specifically addresses in one section the notion of making physical copies of folder structures and getting your head around why this isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is completely okay and that's how I do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to point Github to your projects folder.
There is no need for another redirection. 
If your ready to upload your changes you upload them via `git push origin`